# Как с помощью Devexpress ASP.NET MVC создать отображение данных с MS SQL SEVER в формате Spreadsheet (Excel) в браузере?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, excel, devexpress

Как с помощью Devexpress ASP.NET MVC  создать отображение данных с MS SQL SEVER в формате Spreadsheet (Excel) в браузере?

П.С. С данными, которые будут извлечены и отображены, планируется работать и затем ложить обратно в MS SQL SERVER.

Comment: Совет покажется грубым, но все же. Купи лицензию как я и спрашивай что угодно в тех. поддержке.

Comment: Не уверен , что получится выбить из менеджмента лицензию.

Comment: да, это около 1000$

Comment: Ну тогда точно не выйдет. 

Тем, у кого триал, на вопросы не отвечают в тех. поддержке?

Comment: не получится задать вопрос. Есть кабинет пользователя у зарег. пользователей. У меня лицензия на WinForms. Если напишешь на английском вопрос, то задам его на офиц. сайте. Если ответят, то скину ссылкую

Comment: И нафиг я с java перешел на C#? Эх, где мои сприги с айбернейтами...

Comment: Спасибо, но у меня тематика вроде бы другая.

Comment: Пробовали смотреть [демо](https://demos.devexpress.com/MVCxSpreadsheetDemos/) и [документацию](https://documentation.devexpress.com/AspNet/16157/ASP-NET-WebForms-Controls/Spreadsheet) по `SpreadSheet`? На данный момент не совсем ясно в чем вопрос, с чем именно возникли проблемы.

Comment: Я не знал, что Web Forms это часть ASp.NET MVC =)

Comment: @defaultlocale Тут главная проблема - как это достать с базы, а уж затем отобразить.

Comment: Если уж быть до конца честным, то в Dev Express я полный новичок и не понимаю, что, за чем и как делать. Очень много разного в этом фреймворке.

Comment: Так что то что то в духе SSIS? Drag and use?

Comment: @АнтонЦуркану ссылкой на доки промахнулся, [`SpreadSheet` как MVC Extension тоже есть](https://documentation.devexpress.com/AspNet/17113/ASP-NET-MVC-Extensions/Spreadsheet)

Comment: @АнтонЦуркану то что новичок это не страшно, в нашем деле все постоянно в состоянии новичка в той или иной степени. Тем не менее задавать вопросы в стиле «Я новичок в машиностроении, как построить комбайн?» тоже не дело. Уточните какой именно шаг вызывает затруднения: данные из БД можете получить? элемент можете отобразить? привязать его к данным? Если не можете, то уточните что пробовали и почему не получается.

Comment: @defaultlocale Хорошо, спасибо.

Кажется, нашел кое что то своей проблеме: https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Example/Details/T190813/spreadsheet-how-to-save-and-load-documents-from-a-database

Comment: @АнтонЦуркану вообще, воспользуйтесь триалом DevExpress, он включает в себя демо-проекты с полным кодом. Можно будеть посмотреть и попробовать.

Comment: Всё равно ничего толкового не нашел... Ну не знаю я как взять таблицу с БД и пихнуть её в виде Excel в браузер.